# Why do I get 0 when I print the result of fraction in C?

Tags: c, decimal, fractions, negative-number

I have something like this in my code:

```
a = -2;
b = 1/a;

printf("%d", b);
```

The printf is printing 0. Does anyone know why this is? And what do I do to get -0.5? I also tried `"%.2f"` and that gave me 0.00.

Thanks

Comment: Variable `a` and `b` is declared as `int` in your code, right? try declare one of them as float, then, you will get `-0.5`. And before u print via `%.2f`, the value is already `0`, u just cast from `0` thus the cast result is also `0`.

Comment: @EricWang: Declaring one of them as float wont work. If b is int it cant hold -0.5. If a is int you are again struck into the integer arithmetic problem.

Comment: @lesnar Yeah, u are right, I am imagine  there is another variable c declared as float, and c = a / b, need one of a or b to be float.

Answer (score 3):

You've run into integer arithmetic. In C and many other languages, divisions like `1/2` give you a result you're not expecting because both `1` and `2` are integers, and the result is also an integer. Integers can't store `0.5`, so the result gets its fractional part truncated, and you end up with 0.

To perform fractional arithmetic, you need to use `float`s, `double`s, etc. You can either type that directly as `1.0 / -2.0`, or you can cast your values to other types with `(double) a / b`. As long as at least one of the operands handles fractional parts, your result will also contain fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Since, data types for a and b are not specified i am assuming them to be of type int.

In C, the result of an operation depends on the data types of the operands. The result can not have more precision/accuracy/size than the operands themselves. What you are facing is related to integer arithmetic rules.

Now, in your case: both -2 and 1 in `b = 1/a` are integers so the result will be truncated to an integer, so -1/2 = -0.5 truncated to 0. `%.2f` will not help as the value in b is already 0.

So to cause b to be -0.5. You need to have both a and b as float and print using %f.

or,

You can have a as int and b as float and write b as `1.0/a`. (Here 1 is float a is int so the result will be float typecasting a to int).

or,

via typecasting: `b = 1 / (float)a;`

You need to go through typecasting rules.